# Alternative to Marsala?

Tags: substitutions, wine

Is there a good alternative to Marsala wine?  particularly in [this recipe](http://www.cliffordawright.com/caw/recipes/display/bycategory.php/recipe_id/841/id/2/)

Comment: For what purpose? Marsala can be sweet or dry, young or old, dark or light...

Comment: Don't use dry cooking sherry. Our Marsala and sherry are in near identical bottles and next to each other. I once grabbed the wrong one for chicken Marsala and the whole dish tasted off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using:

- 1/4 c. white wine + 1 tsp brandy ... or go as high as a 2:1 wine to brandy ratio. I like this substitution best personally.
- 1/4 c. white grape juice + 1 tsp brandy
- Madeira wine - I've heard you can use this, but I never have
- Port - again, I've heard it but not used it
- Brandy alone, though I find this to be a bit strong